# Numpad for shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys, kubuntu, kde, plasma-5

I try to assign shortcuts which includes  numpad number keys e.g. Ctrl.+alt+5.

But the numberkeys of numpad won't work only the numberkeys over the qwert keyd

I found out that this seem to be an old bug.

I found this workaround:

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=183458#c17

If I do this the shortcuts are working with the numpad keys too. But now I can't type number with this key in textfields and so on.

How can I make shortcuts so that the numpad numberkeys still work as expected?

Comment: If you assign shortcuts to the keypad, then you won't be able to use the numbers on the keypad. To use them, just add a second key for your shortcut. E.G: To open my email, I've used ALT+6. So for you, use ALT or CTRL or any other with the number previously used.

Comment: You are right. I ve done that but did not mentioned that in my post. I have  updated that.